# Ckeditor only shows a textarea

Tags: 8, forms, wysiwyg

So i created a content type that has a paragraph with a formatted long field in it. The content type itself also has a formatted long field.

These two fields should be ckeditor Full html. But when creating a page i only get a text area and no buttons or anything extra like the select for full html or basic html.

This is as a normal editor who has all right on that content type and paragraph. 
But when i create the same content type as an administrator the Ckeditor does show up.

This makes me think that it has something to do with the custom theme we are using. But i've turned of all the css rules applying to forms and it still doesnt show up.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with my permissions or my theme? Or can it have something to with custom php code in the backend? We are using  some custom written blocks and custom fields.

Comment: There's a permission associated with the filter format as well. Check your user can access full html.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong yeah the have those